# OllyDbg 2.0 Analyze procedure arguments

Tags: reverse-engineering, ollydbg

I've started watching Lena's reversing tutorials, and I've noticed that in the videos, OllyDbg analyzes arguments pass to functions as can be seen here:

[image: OllyDbg analyzes of function arguments]

Now, I didn't use the suggested .ini file inside the tutorials because I use OllyDbg 2 instead of 1.10.
Does anyone know how can I make OllyDbg 2 analyze those arguments and print some comments for easier reading ?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, for anyone having this issue as-well, the problem was that I had to use OllyDbg 2.01 instead of 2.0 .
Version 2.0 doesn't include this feature, so make sure you have the most recent version.